# Python regex to capture a comma-delimited list of items

Tags: python, regex

I have a list of weather forecasts that start with a similar prefix that I'd like to remove. I'd also like to capture the city names:

Some Examples:

> If you have vacation or wedding plans in Phoenix, Tucson, Flagstaff,
>   Salt Lake City, Park City, Denver, Estes Park, Colorado Springs,
>   Pueblo, or Albuquerque, the week will...
>
> If you have vacation or wedding plans for Miami, Jacksonville, Macon,
>   Charlotte, or Charleston, expect a couple systems...
>
> If you have vacation or wedding plans in Pittsburgh, Philadelphia,
>   Atlantic City, Newark, Baltimore, D.C., Richmond, Charleston, or
>   Dover, expect the week...

The strings start with a common prefix "If you have vacation or wedding plans in" and the last city has "or" before it. The list of cities is of variable length.

I've tried this:

```
>>> text = 'If you have vacation or wedding plans in NYC, Boston, Manchester, Concord, Providence, or Portland'
>>> re.search(r'^If you have vacation or wedding plans in ((\b\w+\b), ?)+ or (\w+)', text).groups()
('Providence,', 'Providence', 'Portland')
>>>
```

I think I'm pretty close, but obviously it's not working. I've never tried to do something with a variable number of captured items; any guidance would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Some people, when confronted with a problem, think "I know, I'll use regular expressions." Now they have two problems.

Comment: FWIW, you can to better than ``\w+`` to search for words.  Instead use something like ``[A-Za-z\'\-]+``.  The latter accepts contractions and hypenates but rejects underscores and numbers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import re
s = "If you have vacation or wedding plans for Miami, Jacksonville, Macon, Charlotte, or Charleston, expect a couple systems"
p = re.compile(r"If you have vacation or wedding plans (in|for) ((\w+, )+)or (\w+)")
m = p.match(s)
print m.group(2) # output: Miami, Jacksonville, Macon, Charlotte,
cities = m.group(2).split(", ") # cities = ['Miami', 'Jacksonville', 'Macon', 'Charlotte', '']
cities[-1] = m.group(4) # add the city after or
print cities # cities = ['Miami', 'Jacksonville', 'Macon', 'Charlotte', 'Charleston']
```

the city can be matched by pattern `(\w+, )` and `or (\w+)`
and split cities by pattern `,`

btw, as the pattern is used to many data, [it is preferred to work with the compiled object](https://docs.python.org/2/howto/regex.html#module-level-functions)

PS: the word comes after plan can be `for` or `in`, according to examples you provide

Answer (score 1):

Here is my approach: use the `csv` module to parse the lines (I assume they are in a text file named *data.csv*, please change to suite your situation). After parsing each line:

1. Discard the last cell, it is not a city name
2. Remove *'If ...'* from the first cell
3. Remove or *'or '* from the last cell (used to be next-to-last)

Here is the code:

```
import csv


def cleanup(row):
    new_row = row[:-1]
    new_row[0] = new_row[0].replace('If you have vacation or wedding plans in ', '')
    new_row[0] = new_row[0].replace('If you have vacation or wedding plans for ', '')
    new_row[-1] = new_row[-1].replace('or ', '')
    return new_row

if __name__ == '__main__':
    with open('data.csv') as f:
        reader = csv.reader(f, skipinitialspace=True)
        for row in reader:
            row = cleanup(row)
            print row
```

Output:

```
['Phoenix', 'Tucson', 'Flagstaff', 'Salt Lake City', 'Park City', 'Denver', 'Estes Park', 'Colorado Springs', 'Pueblo', 'Albuquerque']
['Miami', 'Jacksonville', 'Macon', 'Charlotte', 'Charleston']
['Pittsburgh', 'Philadelphia', 'Atlantic City', 'Newark', 'Baltimore', 'D.C.', 'Richmond', 'Charleston', 'Dover']
```

Comment: Yes is the right one. Regular expressions are not useful for problems like this.

Answer (score 1):

Alternative solution here (probably just for sharing and educational purposes).

If you were to solve it with `nltk`, it would be called a [Named Entity Recognition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Named-entity_recognition) problem. Using the snippet based on [`nltk.chunk.ne_chunk_sents()`](http://www.nltk.org/api/nltk.chunk.html#nltk.chunk.ne_chunk_sents), provided [here](https://gist.github.com/onyxfish/322906):

```
import nltk


def extract_entity_names(t):
    entity_names = []

    if hasattr(t, 'label') and t.label:
        if t.label() == 'NE':
            entity_names.append(' '.join([child[0] for child in t]))
        else:
            for child in t:
                entity_names.extend(extract_entity_names(child))

    return entity_names


sample = "If you have vacation or wedding plans in Phoenix, Tucson, Flagstaff, Salt Lake City, Park City, Denver, Estes Park, Colorado Springs, Pueblo, or Albuquerque, the week will..."

sentences = nltk.sent_tokenize(sample)
tokenized_sentences = [nltk.word_tokenize(sentence) for sentence in sentences]
tagged_sentences = [nltk.pos_tag(sentence) for sentence in tokenized_sentences]
chunked_sentences = nltk.ne_chunk_sents(tagged_sentences, binary=True)

entity_names = []
for tree in chunked_sentences:
    entity_names.extend(extract_entity_names(tree))

print entity_names
```

It prints exactly the desired result:

```
['Phoenix', 'Tucson', 'Flagstaff', 'Salt Lake City', 'Park City', 'Denver', 'Estes Park', 'Colorado Springs', 'Pueblo', 'Albuquerque']
```

Answer (score 0):

How about this

```
>>> text = 'If you have vacation or wedding plans for Phoenix, Tucson, Flagstaff, Salt Lake City, Park City, Denver, Estes Park, Colorado Springs, Pueblo, or Albuquerque, the week will'
>>> match = re.search(r'^If you have vacation or wedding plans (in?|for?) ([\w+ ,]+)',text).groups()[1].split(", ")
```

Output

```
>>> match
['Phoenix', 'Tucson', 'Flagstaff', 'Salt Lake City', 'Park City', 'Denver', 'Estes Park', 'Colorado Springs', 'Pueblo', 'or Albuquerque', 'the week will']
```